# How do I remove brackets from keys that have only one item?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['d'], 3: ['e','f'], 4: ['g'], 5: ['h', 'i']}
```

I want to return a dictionary this:

```
d = {1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2:'d', 3: ['e', 'f'], 4: 'g', 5: ['h', 'i']}
```

so far I have:

```
for values in d.values():
    if len(values) == 1:
       ?strip []?
```

Comment: You've got an answer already, so I'll just add this: making this change will actually make your data structure harder to use, since you'll have to decide which way to process it. Unless you are doing this only for printout purposes, it's a bad idea.

Comment: Adding to what @Austin said...  Consider that both lists and strings are iterable, so the obvious way to consume the first dictionary's lists --- iterating over their elements --- is also a _perfectly valid operation_ on the strings that will occasionally appear in their place.  Although operating on individual characters of a string is probably not your goal, it won't even produce a warning from Python.  The output will likely be incorrect but plausible, which is actually _worse_ than blatantly incorrect.

Comment: To further boost what Austin and Kevin are saying: Since it's often very difficult in Python to differentiate between lists and strings, so the way you want the values in the dictionary to be will make it harder to write follow-on code properly since it will then have to deal (differently) with each the two possible types of data, assuming it can tell them apart — therefore doing what you want to do is probably unwise.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be dealing with lists, not strings, as values in your `dict`. Thus, Stripping won't work (even if it were syntactically correct). However, you can simply set the value to the first element of the `list`:

```
for k in d:
    if len(d[k]) == 1:
        d[k] = d[k][0]
```

The brackets `[]` are merely a presentational feature of the underlying type `list`.

Comment: thanks. the issue arrises when I merge dictionaries together. The merged dictionary creates a list for each key. Is there a way to merge dictionaries without creating object type list for keys that have only one value?

Comment: @Cainster That strikes me as a significantly different topic, and should probably be posted as a separate question... assuming it isn't already on Stack Overflow somewhere.

Comment: Rather than using `d[k]`, you can use [`for k,v in d.items(): ...`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
d = {1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['d'], 3: ['e','f'], 4: ['g'], 5: ['h', 'i']}
f= lambda x: x[0] if len(x)==1 else x
{i:f(d[i]) for i in d}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for your submission!  Would you please take a few moments to add an explanation of how your solution works?  This will be helpful as a future reference for users who may encounter the same problem.

Comment: sorry. thats true - im newby here.. trying to get some reputation for bounting my question ) so, second line is [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) look here about.. fits well for small logic. 3-rd line making a dict with calling lambda function with every dictionary element. take a look [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Comment: There's no need to use a lambda or `d[i]` here: `{k: v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k,v in d.items()}`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Comment: I'd also add that this is more robust than the other answer, as it doesn't modify the collection being iterated.